# how to emit multiple objects from NodeJS stream transform phase

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I am receiving a MongoDB cursor with users which I want to transform into a csv.

```
mongodb.find().stream().pipe(csv.transform(user => {
   if (user.is_active) {
       // send object {active: true, user: user.id}
   }
   // send object {user: user.id, random_variable: user.random}
   return {user: user.id, random_variable: user.random}
})).pipe(csv.strigify())
```

My problem is that I want for some users to emit 2 objects/ create 2 rows in the csv.

How to do that ?